# Replace CSS with local file

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I am currently making a google chrome extension, and what I am trying to do is copy one of my local CSS to the webpage, to replace it. This is what I have, but it's not copying them, but instead creating new files. How do I get this to copy my local file instead of create new ones?

```
function ChangeStyle(Style){
    var header =  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
    var oringinal_link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0]
    oringinal_link.remove()
    if(Style === 1){
        $("head").prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/default.css">')
    } else if(Style === 2){
        $("head").prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style1.css">')
    } else if(Style === 3){
        $("head").prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style2.css">')
    }
    console.log("[The Sustainer] Style " + Style + " has been loaded!")
```

This is my content.js file.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you mean by "copy" and "creating new files"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the css file you want to upload in the manifest file as web accesible.

```
{ ...,   
  "web_accessible_resources": ["default.css", "style1.css", "style2.css"],
...}
```

Loading the css file can be done only in your content script.

Comment: How would I be able to do that? >.< Sorry, I'm kind of new to creating extensions.

Comment: You can find the manifest.json file in your working folder. Append the above line in the root element.

Comment: Thanks so much! I would thumbs this up but I currently don't have enough rap :P